# Errorbars in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to create a graph faceted by year and location using the following data, but the error bars are not showing up on my plot.

Below is the data set which I am using -

```
PotatoY_vote <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Year = c(2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,
                       2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,2017L,
                       2017L,2017L,2017L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,
                       2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,2018L,
                       2018L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,
                       2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L,2019L),
           Variety = c("Yusimaap","Yusimaap",
                       "Yusimaap","Yusimaap","Yusimaap","NKK","NKK","NKK","NKK",
                       "NKK","Desiree","Desiree","Desiree","Desiree",
                       "Desiree","Yusimaap","Yusimaap","Yusimaap","Yusimaap",
                       "Yusimaap","NKK","NKK","NKK","NKK","NKK","Desiree",
                       "Desiree","Desiree","Desiree","Desiree","Yusimaap",
                       "Yusimaap","Yusimaap","Yusimaap","Yusimaap","NKK","NKK",
                       "NKK","NKK","NKK","Desiree","Desiree","Desiree",
                       "Desiree","Desiree"),
          Location = c("Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa",
                       "Haa","W/phodrang","Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa","Haa",
                       "W/phodrang","Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa","Haa",
                       "W/phodrang","Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang",
                       "Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang",
                       "Bumthang","Chukha","Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang","Bumthang",
                       "Chukha","Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang","Bumthang",
                       "Chukha","Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang","Bumthang","Chukha",
                       "Gasa","Haa","W/phodrang"),
           Y_Mt_ac = c(12.5,12.6,11.9,9,9.8,9.1,
                       11.5,10.5,8.5,10.9,11.6,8.4,6.5,5.7,6.3,10.6,
                       12.5,11.3,8,9,9.1,11.5,11.5,7.5,10.9,7.6,8.4,7.7,
                       5.7,6.3,11,10.5,11.8,9,9.5,9,10.8,10.5,7,8,
                       7,8,7,6.5,6.9),
            Vote_F = c(62L,210L,47L,90L,131L,57L,
                       180L,28L,71L,104L,31L,120L,15L,49L,95L,111L,
                       125L,75L,109L,117L,85L,110L,43L,72L,88L,50L,71L,
                       20L,53L,65L,91L,88L,43L,53L,101L,65L,60L,33L,
                       38L,81L,42L,44L,26L,35L,58L),
            Vote_M = c(34L,79L,21L,65L,110L,27L,
                       61L,12L,51L,85L,23L,40L,9L,34L,57L,95L,84L,35L,
                       78L,98L,67L,73L,28L,60L,77L,48L,53L,27L,52L,
                       53L,51L,69L,38L,47L,87L,39L,53L,27L,31L,65L,
                       36L,52L,25L,30L,52L),
        V_total_FM = c(96L,289L,68L,155L,241L,84L,
                       241L,40L,122L,189L,54L,160L,24L,83L,152L,206L,
                       209L,110L,187L,215L,152L,183L,71L,132L,165L,98L,
                       124L,47L,105L,118L,142L,157L,81L,100L,188L,
                       104L,113L,60L,69L,146L,78L,96L,51L,65L,110L)
)
```

And below is my code for the graph - all is functioning properly except for the geom_errorbar part of ggplot.

```
    summary_potato2 <- PotatoY_vote %>%
      group_by(Variety, Year, Location) %>%
      summarise(mean_prod2 = mean(Y_Mt_ac), 
                sd2 = sd(Y_Mt_ac), 
                n2 = 1,
                error2 = qnorm(0.95)*sd2/sqrt(n2),
                left2 = mean_prod2 - error2, 
                right2 = mean_prod2 + error2)

    ggplot(data = summary_potato2, aes(x = Variety, y = mean_prod2)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = Variety), stat = "identity", 
               color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) + 
      facet_grid (Year ~ Location) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(x = Variety, y = mean_prod2, ymin = left2, ymax = right2), 
                    color = "blue", width = 0.3) + 
      labs(x = "Variety", y = "Mean Productivity")
```

Comment: Hi Adele, welcome to Stack Overflow. The data that you provided has only one observation per group. Since there is only a single observation, you cannot calculate a standard deviation nor standard error. Therefore, your `summary_potato2` object has only `NA`s for those variables. That is why your code is failing. If you have additional observations that you have not provided, please edit your post with the additional data. Otherwise, you cannot make error bars for the graph in its current form.